# How do I find the radius of convergence and interval of convergence??

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image]
I used the ratio test for this problem and I messed up somewhere in the algebra. Sorry for the messy writing. [image]

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dropped the $n^2$ on the denominator!

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{(n+1)^2}{4(n+1)n^2}x \right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{n+1}{4n^2} x \right| = |x|\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{n+1}{4n^2} \right| = 0$$

From this, we see that this series converges everywhere.

Comment: would that mean the R = 4 and I : (-4,4) ?????

Comment: What we have seen here is that the limit of the ratios is $0$ regardless of $x$. So the series converges for all $x$ so radius of convergence is infinite and the interval of convergence is all real numbers.

Comment: SO what you are saying, please feel free to correct me if I am wrong, but R = infinity and then I : ( - inf, inf) ???

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

The denominator can be written as $4^nn!$

$n!$ grows faster than $x^n$ for all $x$ and $x^n$ grows faster than any polynomial if $|x|>1$ and decays faster than any polynomial if $|x|<1$

Or by the ratio test $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}|(\frac {n+1}{n})^2\frac {x}{4}\frac {1}{n+1}| < 1$ for all $x$